# A puzzle in kindergarten's book

Tags: calculation-puzzle

I found the following puzzle in a kindergarten book:

[image]

Can anyone give a clear explanation as to what the answer is and why?

---

The first time I tried to solve it I got an answer of **6**, by noting that the sum of the top and bottom pair of each set are equal:

For the first:

```
3 6
 7
4 5
```

Where, `3+6 = 4+5`

The second:

```
2 9
 9
8 3
```

`2+9 = 8+3`

And so on.

But this solution completely ignores the centre number, leading me to believe it is wrong! Can anyone think of a better or more logical solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only logical explanation I can come up with at a kindergarten level of knowledge would be that they author intended the child to spot that the $\cup$ and the $\cap$ shape have the same sum, i.e. for

```
3 6
 7
4 5
```

we would have

$$3+7+6=4+7+5$$

As an adult we can very easily spot that we don't need to count the middle one for it to still work however a child may not spot this if they are looking for a pattern which uses all the boxes in each diagram.

This then gives us that

\begin{align}7+5+8&=9+5+?\\
20&=14+?\\
?&=6\end{align}

I tried a few other simple patterns, such as summing diagonals, or adding all the numbers and looking for a pattern between the diagrams but nothing jumped out and I think that is getting quite close to the limit of an average kindergarten child's knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is:

> 8

because:

> add up each set of boxes - 3+6+7+4+5=25, 2+9+9+8+3=31, 7+8+5+9+8=37 for AP(25,6).

Plus:

> the typeset gaps between the sets of boxes are wonky, so obviously this kindergarten puzzle is from a low quality text book.

Comment: I think your answer is good enough for kindergarten! Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

Just a partial answer in all probability:

The missing number is

> `6`

I would be using the following notations for explanation:

```
Top-Right => TR 
Top-Left => TL 
Bottom-Right => BR 
Bottom-Left => BL
```

2 reasons:

1.

> The sum of the numbers in the upper horizontal boxes is the same as that of the lower ones: `TR + TL = BR + BL`, hence: 1st: `3 + 6 = 4 + 5`;    2nd: `2 + 9 = 8 + 3`, which should mean, for the 3rd, `7 + 8 = 9 + BR` ==> **BR = 6**.

2.

> The difference between the numbers in the left vertical boxes is the same as that of the right ones: `BL - TL = TR - BR`, i.e,  1st: `4 -3 = 6 - 5`;    2nd: `8 - 2 = 9 - 3`, which should mean, for the 3rd: `9 - 7 = 8 - BR` ==> **BR = 6**

P.S

> Couldn't figure out what the middle boxes have to do here though.

Comment: Rule 2 is necessarily true if Rule 1 is - rot13(fhogenpg OE naq GY sebz obgu fvqrf) of Rule 1.

Comment: good point @Zanyg. I failed to notice that.

Comment: The middle ones are there to confuse the kids. 4 - 3 = 1 which looks like a seven if written continental European style, 8 -2 = 6 which looks like a 9 if turned upside dow. 9 - 7 = 2 which looks like five if turned upside down :)